# Finding the index of a owl carousel depending on where the user is at on the carousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

as mentioned above, is there a way to obtain the index of the carousel?

[image]

I want to change the text (indicated in the red arrow) based on the position of where the user is (blue arrow). I

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Owl Carousel 2 - how to get a current item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447223/owl-carousel-2-how-to-get-a-current-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use carousel events as per the [document](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html). Please try the below code.

```js
var owl;
$(document).ready(function(){
  owl = $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 300,
    loop: false,
    navSpeed: 300,
    items: 1,
    margin: 2
  });
  owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    $('#continue-btn').html('Continue ' + e.item.index);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 120px;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"> slide1 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide2 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide3 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide4 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide5 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide6 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide7 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide8 </div>
  <div class="item"> slide9 </div>
</div>
<button id="continue-btn">
Continue
</button>
```